# Prove that $(n, n + 1) = 1$ for all $n \gt 0$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I was thinking of doing this by contradiction.  So by supposing:
$$(n, n + 1) \neq 1$$

Then trying to to show that $(n, n + 1) \gt 1$ or $(n, n + 1) \lt 1$.  But I'm not sure how I can accomplish this.

I also thought about the fact that $n$ and $n + 1$ are always of different parity.  So if $n$ is even, then $n + 1$ is odd.  But I don't think that helps me.

Comment: Assuming that the parentheses denote $\text{gcd}$, how could it be less than 1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT: If $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$, then $d \mid a-b$.

Comment: Now that seemed elementary :).  Thanks!

Comment: @icanc: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 7):

If $d$ divides $n$ and $d$ divides $n+1$, then $d$ divides $(n+1)-n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Common multiples $\rm\,n\ne m\,$ of $\rm\,d\,$ are no closer than $\rm\,d\:$(why?) $ $ Thus $\rm\,m = n\!+\!1\:\Rightarrow\: d \le \,\ldots$